# How to make jQuery more effective in appending imgs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want images to represent fields and I need many of them.

Lets say that I need 10 x 10 fields. Good part about this is that all the images are small and there are only about 3 images of different colors that are used again and again.

My jQuery code takes too long to do this so I am sure I did something wrong.What is more effective way to do the same ?

```
 for(y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {

      for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {

        var imgId = "imgXY"+ "_" + x + "_" + y;

        console.log("appending " + imgId);

        $('#game').append('<img id="'+ imgId + '" src="gray.png" />');
        //some positioning and css code

      }
}
```

Comment: [The code you posted runs in an instant for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/mLht2hzv/) Have you debugged yet? Try to include a full repro for your scenario. Try to use the debugging / dev tools to see where the culprit is.

Comment: Use pure (vanilla) js instead of jQuery it will slightly improve perfs but as @Jeroen said what you posted is already running fast. Also, cache $("#game") and use the reference to it, it will stop jQ traversing the DOM at each loop.

Comment: @Jeroen It migh run instant but I ask for case where  I could have 100 x 100 and slower machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var html = "";
for(y = 1; y <= 10; y++){
    for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        var imgId = "imgXY"+ "_" + x + "_" + y;
        console.log("appending " + imgId);
        html += '<img id="'+ imgId + '" src="gray.png" />';
        //add positioning and css code inline
    }
}
$('#game').append(html);
```

This way, #game only needs to be searched for once, and there will only be one call updating the DOM content.

Comment: Ofc remove the log once you're done because it's slowing the code. This way is good anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're making a grid of 100 total images here, inserting into the DOM each time.

DOM manipulation is notoriously slow, so an optimization you could make here would be to first compute all the elements, then do your `.append()` to the #game element at the last possible moment.

This might look something like:

```
var html = "";
for(y = 1; y <= 10; y++){
  for (x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    var imgId = "imgXY"+ "_" + x + "_" + y;
    html += '<img id="'+ imgId + '" src="gray.png" />';
   }
}
$('#game').append(html);
```

Comment: The essential idea is -- minimize DOM manipulations / inserts where you can, and things should run much faster.